# react native IOS app crash when restart or send to other device

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, appium

we are testing IOS app on python selenium, Appium, our client made the app with react native, when I built the app it will work fine, but once I shutdown/ or restart my device or even send it to another device it will crash, I searched for this but did not find any helpful things. and I don't think it has anything with Appium because this will happen even without running it.
why is it happening?
I do not know anything about react native, is there any token for the build on react-native?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what was happening, I was building the debug version, it will only work when the react-native terminal window is active, to make it work I used
 `npx react-native run-ios --configuration Release`
and it's working fine now